# Get the most probable color from a words set

Tags: language-agnostic, nlp

Are there any libraries existing or methods that let you to figure out the most probable color for a words set? For example, cucumber, apple, grass, it gives me green color. Did anyone work in that direction before?

Answer (score 2):

If i have to do that, i will try to search images based on the words using google image or others and recognize the most common color of top n results.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a pretty reasonable NLP problem and one thats very easy to handle via map-reduce.

Identify a list of words and phrases that you call colors ['blue', 'green', 'red', ...].
Go over a large corpus of sentences, and for the sentences that mention a particular color, for every other word in that sentence, note down `(word, color_name)` in a file. (Map Step)

Then for each word you have seen in your corpus, aggregate all the colors you have seen for it  to get something like `{'cucumber': {'green': 300, 'yellow': 34, 'blue': 2}, 'tomato': {'red': 900, 'green': 430'}...}` (Reduce Step)

Provided you use a large enough corpus (something like wikipedia), and you figure out how to prune really small counts, rare words, you should be able to make pretty comprehensive and robust dictionary mapping millions of the items to their colors.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do that is to do a text search in google for combinations of colors and the word in question and take the combination with the highest number of results. Here's a quick Python script for that:

```
import urllib
import json
import itertools

def google_count(q):
      query = urllib.urlencode({'q': q})
      url = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web?v=1.0&%s' % query
      search_response = urllib.urlopen(url)
      search_results = search_response.read()
      results = json.loads(search_results)
      data = results['responseData']
      return int(data['cursor']['estimatedResultCount'])

colors = ['yellow', 'orange', 'red', 'purple', 'blue', 'green']

# get a list of google search counts
res = [google_count('"%s grass"' % c) for c in colors]
# pair the results with their corresponding colors
res2 = list(itertools.izip(res, colors))
# get the color with the highest score
print "%s is %s" % ('grass', sorted(res2)[-1][1])
```

This will print:

```
grass is green
```

Comment: Or you can do the search in ImageNet (http://www.image-net.org/) which provides images to Wordnet entries, so you will likely get more accurate images. Using Google search, "Apple" for example may show the tech company instead of the fruit.

Answer (score 0):

Daniel's and Xi.lin's answers are very good ideas. Along the same axis, we could combine both with an approach similar to Xilin's but more simple: Query Google Image with the word you want to find the color associated with + a "Color" filter (see in the lower left bar). And see which color yields more results.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a tightly defined set of sources if possible such as Wikipedia and [Wordnet](http://wordnet.princeton.edu/).
Here, for example, is Wordnet for "panda":

*S: (n) giant panda, panda, panda bear, coon bear, Ailuropoda melanoleuca
(large black-and-white herbivorous mammal of bamboo forests of China and Tibet;
in some classifications considered a member of the bear family or of a separate
family Ailuropodidae)*

*S: (n) lesser panda, red panda, panda, bear cat, cat bear,
Ailurus fulgens (reddish-brown Old World raccoon-like carnivore;
in some classifications considered unrelated to the giant pandas)*

Because of the concise, carefully constructed language it is highly likely that any colour words will be important. Here you can see that pandas are both black-and-white and reddish-brown.

If you identify subsections of Wikipedia (e.g. "Botanical Description") this will help to increase the relevance of your results. Also the first image in Wikipedia is very likely to be the best "definitive" one.

But, as with all statistical methods, you will get false positives (and negatives , though these are probably less of a problem).